# BURG menu error

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 recently and installed BURG (bootloader based on GRUB). However, the boot menu seems to have swapped Vista and Windows Recovery mode; so to go to Vista I need to select the 'recovery mode'. How can I fix this?

Comment: For non-standard tech like that (because I've never heard of it :-), you better go ask on the project ML or IRC. Also, come back and share with us your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Super Boot Manager is a dream for controlling things like burg, grub, and plymouth.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install buc super-boot-manager
```

from:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/super-boot-manager-eases-burg-grub-plymouth-tweaking-pains/